# Virtual machines in a LVM partition or not?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, lvm

When you create a virtual machine on Debian (with kvm-qemu), the .img file is placed in  `/var/lib/libvirt/images` by default.

Do you advise creating an LVM partition specifically for the vm's?

Lets assume I have two LVM partitions: `/` and `/home`. When I start a snapshot of `/` , could the mechanism be disturbed by the vm's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A running virtual machine is like any other program: it may be writing to its disk-image file while other things are going on.

According to the [LVM HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html):

> A snapshot volume is a special type of volume that presents all the data that was in the volume at the time the snapshot was created. For a more detailed description, see [Section 3.8](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html), Snapshots. This means we can back up that volume without having to worry about data being changed while the backup is going on, and we don't have to take the database volume offline while the backup is taking place.

and [at least one guide](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BackupKVMGuest) indicates that doing a snapshot is enough:

> The method employs LVM to take a snapshot of the guest disk and then uses rsync to update changes to a previous backup on a remote server. If there is a database server on the guest then it is flushed & locked at the point the snapshot is taken. This method came into use around 2006 following wider availability and awareness of virtualization software, processor enhancements, cheaper faster network bandwidth, and cheaper bigger disks.

If you really want to be certain that you have captured the machine in a known state, you may still want to shut down the virtual machine because its *memory* may hold data which has not been written to disk (and which would be saved if the virtual machine were shut down).

Putting the virtual machines in a partition devoted to them would simplify making snapshots using LVM, since then you could restore the partition with just their data.  You would find it inconvenient to restore "/" just to get those machines back, since your *own* machine's `/var` is included in the root partition (since only two partitions were mentioned).

Further reading:

- [13.4. Taking a Backup Using Snapshots](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html) (LVM HOWTO)
- [Backing up a running virtual machine](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BackupKVMGuest)

Comment: OK. What I retain is that the vm's continue to run during a snapshot without perturbation and vice versa. I don't need to use use a special partition for them. Thank you.